# make pagination in papaya dicom viewer slices using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, papaya

i'm using papaya API from github

In this papaya dicom viewer, I want to integrate few things.

One is pagination. if i try to edit this API, I'm getting error

**What i want:-**

1. In the papaya viewer NEXT, PREV is working fine but I want to make
   On click to FIRST and the LAST slice moving.
2. And also the pagination will be 1,2,3,4...If click ONE first slice
   should appear.

Advance thanks

Comment: I haded the answer in down below if you have any query comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After download Papaya medical research image viewer, choose to work **test** folder file, So that you can understand how papaya Dicom viewer working.

**Step 1:-**

In the js folder open ***constants.js*** file and create the constants

```
var MOVE_TO_FIRST_SLICE = "move-to-first-slice",
    MOVE_TO_LAST_SLICE = "move-to-last-slice";
    PAGINATION_LIST = "pagination-list";
```

**Step2:-**

Now open the ***viewer.js***, create this on click functions FIRST, LAST and 1,2,3... slices(data-value).

```
    $(this.container.containerHtml.find("#" + MOVE_TO_FIRST_SLICE + this.container.containerIndex)).click(function () {
        viewer.firstLastSlice(false);
    });

    $(this.container.containerHtml.find("#" + MOVE_TO_LAST_SLICE + this.container.containerIndex)).click(function () {
        viewer.firstLastSlice(true)
    });

    $(this.container.containerHtml.find("." + PAGINATION_LIST + this.container.containerIndex)).click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('value');
        viewer.pagination(id);
    });
```

**Step 3:-**
And open the ***main.js*** and create the elements

```
papaya.Container.fillContainerHTML = function (containerHTML, isDefault, params, replaceIndex) {

containerHTML.append("<button type='button' id='"+ (MOVE_TO_FIRST_SLICE + index) + "' class='" + MOVE_TO_FIRST_SLICE + "'>First</button> ");
containerHTML.append("<button type='button' id='"+ (PAPAYA_CONTROL_MAIN_INCREMENT_BUTTON_CSS + index) + "' class='" + PAPAYA_CONTROL_MAIN_INCREMENT_BUTTON_CSS + "'><</button> ");

                var max = 23;
                var slice;
                for(slice=1; slice<=max; slice++){
containerHTML.append("<button id='"+ (PAGINATION_LIST + index) +"' class='"+ (PAGINATION_LIST + index) + "' data-value='" + slice + "'  OnClick(" + slice +") >" + slice + "</button>");
                    }

containerHTML.append("<button id='"+ (PAPAYA_CONTROL_MAIN_DECREMENT_BUTTON_CSS + index) + "' class='" + PAPAYA_CONTROL_MAIN_DECREMENT_BUTTON_CSS + "'>></button> ");              
                containerHTML.append("<button type='button' id='"+ (MOVE_TO_LAST_SLICE + index) + "' class='" + MOVE_TO_LAST_SLICE + "'>Last</button> ");
               containerHTML.append("<button type='button' id='"+ (GET_MAX_VALUE + index) + "' class='" + GET_MAX_VALUE + index + "'>TesT</button> ");
}
```

**Step4:-**

The below functions are important to move slices ***viewer.js***

```
//pagination 1,2,3
papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.pagination = function (id, paginationList) {
    var max =  this.volume.header.imageDimensions.zDim;
    //console.log(id);
    this.currentCoord.z = id;
    this.gotoCoordinate(this.currentCoord);

   };

// firstLastSlice
papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.firstLastSlice = function (flSlice, degree) {
    var max = this.volume.header.imageDimensions.zDim;
    if (degree === undefined) {
        degree = 0; 
    }

    if (flSlice) {
        this.currentCoord.z = max;
    } else {
        this.currentCoord.z = 0;
    }

    this.gotoCoordinate(this.currentCoord);
};
```

**Explanation**

1. *viewer.js* calculated total slices `this.volume.header.imageDimensions.zDim;` and stored the total count in ***Max*** variable. If the `this.currentCoord.z = max;` It will go to last slice else, If the `this.currentCoord.z = 0;` It will move to first slice.
2. In pagination on click to passed data-value to viewer.js pagination function and if `this.currentCoord.z = id`(id <=> data-value ) It will move to particular slice.

After click using this function `this.gotoCoordinate(this.currentCoord);` the slice will move.